# onActivityResult seems to be not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

*MainActivity.java* - Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView ClockButton;

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private TextView[] textViews;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textViews=new TextView[20];

        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

        ClockButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ClockIconButton);
        ClockButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onChangeContentView()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onChangeContentView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//test
        hours=Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("H"));
        minutes=Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("M"));

        for(int i=0;i<textViews.length;i++)
        {
            if(textViews[i]==null)
            {
                textViews[i].setText(hours+" : "+minutes);
                linearLayout.addView(textViews[i]);

                break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

*MainActivity2.java* - Sub class

```
 public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView OkButton;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        OkButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.OkIcon);
        OkButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.TimePicker1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        hours = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
        minutes = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("H", hours);
        intent.putExtra("M", minutes);
        setResult(1, intent);

        finish();
    }


}
```

I've tried to fix it. It's no problem, but I can't see the the `Toast` which is called in `onActivityResult()` in my Main class. (`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`)

What am I missing out on?

Comment: can you post your manifest? also did your code go to the `MainActivity2 `? class

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="qu.clock">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="qu.clock.MainActivity2">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: sorry I can't write XML files in question

Comment: did u have `android:noHistory="false"` in manifest?

Comment: I've realised to edit "android:noHistory"  but It's still doesn't work     is there anything I have to do?

Comment: you have to set `noHistory` to `true` and did your code go to the `MainActivity2` class?

Comment: Here is an [Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Comment: I did it and went over all to find but It doesn't show me Toast.make().show()         my edited code is just add android:noHistory="true" in MainActivity2 of Manifast              is there any problem?

Comment: *"It doesn't show me Toast.make().show()"* what does it show? You need to explain what doesn't and what **does** happen so we can have a better understanding. Also, your manifest code should go in your post using the "edit" button below the tags.

Comment: I used Toast.make().show() to know if onActivityResult can work

Answer (score 0):

int RESULT_OK
Standard activity result: operation succeeded.

Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)

[android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK)

Do like this:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: I replaced setResult(1,intent) to setResult(RESULT_OK) but It's not show me Toast.make().show()  how can I do?

Comment: as well setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);